# Finding out with process binds a hotkey

Tags: hotkeys

Somehow I have set a hotkey that start DoubleCommander whenever I press AltGr+s. Unfortunately I forgot which program is responsible for that behavior and therefore how to change it back.

How do I find out which program is responsible to change it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Hotkey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) to list the responsible program.

Answer (score 0):

click anywhere on your screen and select Graphics Options and then Hot Keys and then Disable.

Comment: I don't find it in that list it seems to paper via a different process.